# Python ElasticSearch dsl: How do I represent a field to be a mapping from a string to a list of ints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

The structure of the document I want to insert looks like this:

```
post = {
          "day_1_scores": [1,2,3], 
          "day_2_scores":[4,5,6]
}
```

I'm aware that `elasticsearch_dsl` has several custom datatypes such as `Document`, `Integer`, but I'm not sure how to make a map that maps from a `string` to a list of `ints`

For example, if I wanted to create a Post with a `string` attribute called `content`, I'd go:

```
class Post(Document):
    content = Text(analyzer='snowball', fields={'raw': Keyword()})

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        print("saving post")
        super(Post, self).save(**kwargs)


    class Index:
        name = 'blog'
        doc_type = "post"
```

When I need to insert it into the DB, I'd call `save` method.

But I want, is for this Post to have another attribute: a map that maps from a `string` to a list of `ints`

Answer (score 1):

In elasticsearch there's no special mapping for lists. If a doc field contains a list of values then that field type is the type of an item in the list.

If you are indexing a field, with numbers values, and elasticsearch consider it as a string, then that field values are surrounded with quotes. If you can't control the code that added the quotes you can:
1. Add mapping to the index, stating that the field is a number. 
OR
2. Add "numeric_detection" to the index mapping.

Both options would do what you are looking for - consider that specific field as a number (even if it is array)